# Pull DB data into drop down in MYSQL, PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make select option by getting DB values into a drop down, following is my code that I have used,

```
$query = "SELECT apply_year FROM emp_leaves ORDER BY apply_year DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<select name='apply_year' class=\"form-control\"><option>Select Year</option>";
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value=" . $r['leave_id'] . ">" . $r['apply_year'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>"; ?>
```

It work fine, But I want to show only one value of each years, I want to avoid repeat same year in drop down. Please help

Comment: how can you get the leave_id value when you only have "apply_year" in your query? - I also agree with the use of "distinct"  as @Dhara Parmar said  but you might also try "GROUP BY apply_year" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DISTINCT for apply_year and Create mysql query like, so that it will return apply_year only once in result:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT apply_year FROM emp_leaves ORDER BY apply_year DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$query = "SELECT apply_year FROM emp_leaves GROUP BY apply_year  ORDER BY apply_year DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<select name='apply_year' class=\"form-control\"><option>Select Year</option>";
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo "<option value=" . $r['leave_id'] . ">" . $r['apply_year'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>"; ?>
```